# How to store the print of a variable as string in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

Suppose I have a variable that is not a string, however, when I print it out it gives a string. For simplicities sake and for giving an example say that the variable is

```
message = "Hello Python world!"
```

Although, this is a string (Suppose it is not)

I would like to store a new variable A as the print statment of this message i.e.

```
A=print(message)
```

When I code `A` on the other line or `print(A)` it does not give me any outcome.

```
IN: A
Out: 
IN: print(A)
Out: None
```

Can someone help me figure this out?

Comment: Do you mean you want to grab the string-representation of a var? like `A=str(message)`?

Comment: @rx2 I am sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you're looking for something like this:

```
var = 123
A = str(var)  # A is now '123'
```

The `print()` function doesn't return anything; it simply prints to the standard output stream. Internally, though, it converts non-string arguments to strings, as in the example code above.